# Getting error in Hive : vertex failed failed due to Root_Input_init_failure, how much we can increase the memory while using Tez?

Tags: hive, apache-tez

Getting error in Hive : vertex failed #some vertex name# Killed/failed due to Root_Input_init_failure

Comment: Update the below parameter:  set hive.auto.convert.join=false;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is a memory problem; the parameter is
tez.am.resource.memory.mb  which is the size of a container.
The number of container is function of the evaluated size of the data source.
With crypto, a common workaround is (vertices crash due to changing format betwwen map and reduc)

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=false;
```